# Vivado Hls-Coding Compilation Error

Tags: c

During simulation, i am getting this error code : "csim_design" failed :nonzero return value && “Port has no Fanin or fanout and is left dangling.  Please check my code, TOP FUNCTION Name: Trail_NTB, and if it wrong please correct it

```
void Trail_NTB()
{
   int static numbers[]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int i,result;
   for(i=0;i<=4;i++);
   {
       result=numbers[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with HLS you are building HW on FPGA. This HW can exist if there are some inputs and some outputs. In this case, your C code cannot be translated in RTL: your box will have no input-output buses and will be not able to interact with the surrounding world. Also, if you read the ERROR is saying: "**Port has no Fanin or fanout and is left dangling.**"

Comment: Yes, you are right, i am going to build FPGA. For that i am learning and practicing C codes in HLS. Please suggest me which Program Language is best to build FPGA.

Comment: Saras, if the answer was helpful please accept it (with the tic where you can vote up my answer: it will become green). To start with HLS use this link: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_4/ug871-vivado-high-level-synthesis-tutorial.pdf. Try to replicate everything!!